# Fastest and pythonic way of joining the last few elements of a list and append the newly joined items back to the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Suppose I have the below list and I want to be able to join the last three items
in each list and put the joined items back to the original list. How would i go about doing that using something like list comp? I know how to do it by writing an elaborate lines of codes, however what I'm looking for is an efficient one or two liner code that will accomplish what I want to do.

**My list:**

```
lines = [
 ['0', 'AG1C', 'A', '05/27/2020', '10:20', 'PM'],
 ['1', 'AG1C', 'B', '05/27/2020', '1:22', 'PM'],
 ['2', 'AG1C', 'B', '05/16/2020', '12:58', 'AM'],
 ['3', 'AG1C', 'C', '05/17/2020', '10:34', 'AM'],
 ['4', 'AG1C', 'C', '05/28/2020', '2:10', 'AM']]
```

**Here's what I tried and didn't work:**

```
lines = [line[:2].append(f'{line[-2]} {line[-1]}') for line in lines]
```

**My desired output:**

```
print(lines)

[['0', 'AG1C', 'A', '05/27/2020 10:20 PM'],
 ['1', 'AG1C', 'B', '05/27/2020 1:22 PM'],
 ['2', 'AG1C', 'B', '05/16/2020 12:58 AM'],
 ['3', 'AG1C', 'C', '05/17/2020 10:34 AM'],
 ['4', 'AG1C', 'C', '05/28/2020 2:10 AM']]
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this can you help:

```
 x = [[line[0], line[1], line[2], ' '.join(line[3:])] for line in lines]
 print(x)
```

Output:

```
[['0', 'AG1C', 'A', '05/27/2020 10:20 PM'], 
 ['1', 'AG1C', 'B', '05/27/2020 1:22 PM'],
 ['2', 'AG1C', 'B', '05/16/2020 12:58 AM'],
 ['3', 'AG1C', 'C', '05/17/2020 10:34 AM'],
 ['4', 'AG1C', 'C', '05/28/2020 2:10 AM']]
```

Comment: ah, I was trying to get something like this to work `[[l[:len(l) - 3], " ".join(l[len(l) - 3:])] for l in lines]`

Comment: Thank you but this code assumes you know the len of your list already.

Answer (score 1):

You were actually really close to the correct answer. The problem in your solution is that .append does not return the actual list, it just modifies the list in place and returns None. For that you can sum 2 lists which will return another list like this:

```py
lines = [line[:2] + [f"{line[-2]} {line[-1]}"] for line in lines]
```

Now the problem is that the items with index 2 and 3 are being ignored

```py
lines = [line[:3] + [f"{line[-3]} {line[-2]} {line[-1]}"] for line in lines]
```

This returns the desired output, but there are still some things to change.

Also that f-string doesn't look "pythonic". Another way to do that would be to get a list of the last 3 elements and use the string join method like this:

```py
lines = [line[:3] + [" ".join(line[-3:])] for line in lines]
```

This only works for this specific case where the original lists have length 6.

```py
lines = [line[:-3] + [" ".join(line[-3:])] for line in lines]
```

Using `line[:-3]` will get all the elements except for the last 3. This is the general solution.

Comment: ahhhhh, I see `[l[:len(l) - 3] + [" ".join(l[len(l) - 3:])] for l in lines]`. I didn't know you could append that way.

Comment: Yeah in python when you index using negative numbers it is implied you are doing length minus that number. `len(l)` is not usually explicitly written out but it is no different

Comment: `[line[:-3] + [" ".join(line[-3:])] for line in lines]` I think it's a good solution if you don't know the length of the list

Comment: No, no. I mean I didn't know you could take a list ["s", "t", "o",] and add in another item with + ["p"], like so. Very nice to know!

Comment: Oh yeah it's a neat trick to know and use. Btw if this answered your question you can click the checkbox and accept the answer

Comment: This ```lines = [line[:3] + [" ".join(line[-3:])] for line in lines]```  is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for pointing of what i was doing wrong on my code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another way to do this:

```
lines = [line[:3] + [' '.join(line[3:])] for line in lines]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another readable approach without slicing:

```
lines = [[a, b, c, " ".join(d)] for a, b, c, *d in lines]
```

Comment: Nice!  What would the same code look like, if I have a large number of elements and I want to join the last three?

Comment: That would be more difficult. I don't think it can be done reasonably without slicing `[[*line[:-3], " ".join(line[-3:])] for line in lines]`

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = [
 ['0', 'AG1C', 'A', '05/27/2020', '10:20', 'PM'],
 ['1', 'AG1C', 'B', '05/27/2020', '1:22', 'PM'],
 ['2', 'AG1C', 'B', '05/16/2020', '12:58', 'AM'],
 ['3', 'AG1C', 'C', '05/17/2020', '10:34', 'AM'],
 ['4', 'AG1C', 'C', '05/28/2020', '2:10', 'AM']]

for i in lines:
    last_items = ' '.join(i[3:len(i)])
    for k in range(3):
        i.remove(i[-1])
    i.append(last_items)
print(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

One line of code:

```
for i in range(len(lines)): lines[i][3:] = [' '.join(lines[i][3:])]
```

Output:

```
[['0', 'AG1C', 'A', '05/27/2020 10:20 PM'],
 ['1', 'AG1C', 'B', '05/27/2020 1:22 PM'], 
 ['2', 'AG1C', 'B', '05/16/2020 12:58 AM'], 
 ['3', 'AG1C', 'C', '05/17/2020 10:34 AM'],
 ['4', 'AG1C', 'C', '05/28/2020 2:10 AM']]
```